# Find lowest cost of a boat ride, Using Recursion and Memoization

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, grid, memoization

thats my code:

```
def O_C(n, prices, start=1, memo=None):
    if start == n:
        return 0
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
    if start not in memo:
        options = []
        for i in range(start + 1, n + 1):
            options.append(prices(start, i) + O_C(n, prices, i, memo))
        memo[start] = min(options)
    return memo[start]

# O_C stands for Optimal Cost

def make_random_prices(N):
    import random
    prices = {}
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, N + 1):
            prices[(i, j)] = random.randint(1, 10*N)
    return prices

prices = make_random_prices(100)
print O_C(100, prices)
```

the error i keep constantly getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ori/Desktop/OneDrive - mail.tau.ac.il/Python/test/recursion.py", line 48, in <module>
    print O_C(100, prices)
  File "/Users/Ori/Desktop/OneDrive - mail.tau.ac.il/Python/test/recursion.py", line 32, in O_C
    options.append(prices(start, i) + O_C(n, prices, i, memo))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Cannot find any reference on this site, nor in any other, to this error in this context.
The recursion call might be wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting `prices(start, i)` to do? Did you mean `prices[(start, i)]`, as you do in `make_random_prices`?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `prices[(start, i)]` instead of prices(start, i)?

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. You are trying to call an object of type `dict`. You can see that `prices` is a `dict`, you defined it as such `prices = {}`. Then, in `O_C` you try to call it: `prices(start, i)` but `dict` type is not callable.

Comment: THANKS!!! I knew it would be the smallest problem :) kept looking for the problems with my memoization implementation! didn't even think to look there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error explains itself quite well. In the following line of code,

```
options.append(prices(start, i) + O_C(n, prices, i, memo))
```

use `prices[(start, i)]` to access the value in **prices** keyed by the tuple `(start, i)` instead of trying to call **prices** by `prices(start, i)`. **prices** here is a dict, not a callable.